# I have a generated a QR code but the source code does not scan the generated QR code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a generated a QR code but the source code does not scan the generated QR code.

I have a QR code scanner template but it does not scan the generated QR code.
It can only Generate a QR code but it does not scan the Code.

The onPressed method is supposed to be scanning the generated code.

I get this error when I click the floating Button
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner)`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
//import 'package:qr_code';;
import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Flutter QR"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String barcode = "";

  Future scanBarcode() async {
    String barcodeResult = await scanner.scan();
    setState(() {
      barcode = barcodeResult;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            /*QrImage(
              data: "Savanna, R25",
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              size: 200,
            )*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => scanBarcode(),
        tooltip: "increment",
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Pubspec.yaml file with plugins

```
name: fluttersqflite
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  qr_flutter: ^3.0.1
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^0.1.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: did u add the plugin during debugging? If yes, then maybe you have to stop and restart the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this plugin- [qrscan](https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan)

and in your dart file write this:-

**import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;**

Function for scan:-

```html
Future _scan() async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scan();
setState(() {
      barcode = barcodeResult;
    });
  }
```

And in your floating action button:-

```html
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=>_scan(),
        tooltip: "increment",
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
```

And ya remember to add permission for this dependency

Comment: I have added everything as you instructed as well as the permissions but the app does not scan, it just outputs the scan screen but with no box with a line that shows its ready to scan, I have edited my question with the latest code

Comment: Can you add the pick of the scan screen and try scanning a different qr code